# A special character added during ByteArrayOutputStream conversion

Tags: java

I have a XmlObject which has the correct value what i needed.
Ex : 1½-2Y

But when i tried to convert it into byte of stream, the result i am seeing as 1Â½-2Y.

Sample code :

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
Class MyClass implements XmlBuilder<T> {

protected final String serializeToXml(XmlObject xmlObject) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        xmlObject.save(os,createXmlOptions());   /Its adding a special char here
        return os.toString(); 
  }
}
protected final XmlOptions createXmlOptions() {
    final XmlOptions xmlOptions = new XmlOptions();
    xmlOptions.setValidateOnSet();
    xmlOptions.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8_ENCODING);
    return xmlOptions;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.toString()` will internally call `new String(buffer)` and thus will use the system encoding which I assume is *not* UTF-8.

In general you should explicitly provide the encoding, e.g. `new String( os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8")`.

Comment: It worked and i changed my byteArrayOutputStream from os.toString() to new String( os.toByteArray(), UTF_8_ENCODING). Thank you :)